# Changing placement of label to be underneath curved line ArcMap Maplex label manger?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, labeling, line, rivers

I'm working on a labeling rivers in an ArcMap project. For rivers but one the standard river placement works but I need a way to place the label of one river below the river not above like the standard placement. I can't for the life of me find an option in the Maplex labeling engine to do this.

Is there a way to force a label of line feature to lie underneath the line?

[image]

Comment: Perhaps you could add some markup to the image to show where exactly you want the label?

Comment: I'm not familiar with this can you explain that a little bit?

Comment: I suppose you made that screenshot with ArcMap? So, you could add a label using the *Text* tool on the *Draw* toolbar. Then make a screenshot and [add](https://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/418393/edit) it to your question

Comment: And while you're at it, could you also explain why exactly you want this?

Comment: The reason is aesthetics mostly.  The label runs off the map and I want to keep on the map. No matter what I tried part of the label would run off the map. So I wanted to try to label underneath the line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Labeling panel after choosing "Curved and offset" you need to click on the "offset" button to access this option (as my UI is in french you may find that my translation of the button name are not accurate but the picture should help )

[image]

---

I notice that this option is not available with the river placement (you may try the "Curved and offset" placement with standard setting and below line option and see if that work for you)

Comment: Thanks this was a good work around. I was able to get the desired effect by switching over to regular placement. It's frustrating you can't choose below the line for river style.